# Why this CKEditor control doesn't work well?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, ckeditor

I'm trying to use [this wysiwyg editor](http://ckeditor.com/) in an asp.net application. But It doesn't work..

So I add reference to the DLL and make this asp code:

```
<%@ Page MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="test.aspx.cs" Inherits="test" Title="Tests" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="CKEditor.NET" Namespace="CKEditor.NET" TagPrefix="CKEditor" %>




<asp:Content ID="headContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat ="server" >


</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<div>

  <CKEditor:CKEditorControl ID="test" runat="server">test</CKEditor:CKEditorControl>   


</div>

</asp:Content>
```

And the result is

[image]

So it seems it is missign something.. I try to add TooBar = "Full" in the control's properties but it doen't work. Can someone using this control help me?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would check whether some Javascript errors occur on page loading. They can provide information about the problem - missing some JS files of CKEditor etc.

Comment: Thanks there is a syntax error in CKEditor js file.. I think I'll search another Wysiwyg editor..

Comment: @bAN CKEditor is one of the best WYSIWYG editors..I really doubt there would be syntax error in the source.. Maybe the problem is somewhere else. Are all CKEditor sources accesible for web browser?

Answer (score 1):

Also the default location for ckeditor which contains all js ,css and image files is in the website root and if you miss this you can only the textarea without style
hope it helps others
to change the default path of ckeditor folder use BasePath property

Answer (score 0):

I might be a bit late on responding, but ensure you have copied the ckeditor folder into your solution.

[Absolute Beginner's CKEditor for ASP.NET Control Integration Guide](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/ASP.NET/Integration_Beginners)